# Firefox padding not working properly

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding

I have one button.Apply the padding to this button.But is not like same size with chrome and  Firefox

run the below the snippet with `Firefox` and `chrome`  you could see the difference.How to rectify the problem

```css
button{
padding:5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<button>hello</button>
```

**Firefox** version `54.0`

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Please Don't mark as a  duplicate .i was searched and tried many of the same question answer.but its not working

Thanks,

Comment: wich version of ffx are you getting this issue, in own looks same as chrome

Comment: use the reset css, Normalize.css for Make browsers render all elements more consistently.

Comment: Can’t reproduce that, the buttons look about the same size in Chromium and Firefox. Default border-width applied via the user agent stylesheet seems to be different, according to DOM inspector; but it looks nothing as extreme as your screenshots for me.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón `FF v 54.0`

Comment: @CBroe any option with overwrite the border-width?

Comment: same 54.0.1 (32-bit

Comment: firefox 54: Height: 1px border, 5px padding, 14px height, 5px padding, 1px border.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dvJ1Sv

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón version is not problem i was updated it .But some of the user using this type of lower version .how to handle this type error.That why i was asking

Comment: From the code you posted on your question; how would anyone ever know the problem was with `font-family`, as you don't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer From my way .**`Its a font problem`** .Different font family its have some default font size  on chrome browser its not same with all other browser

```css
button{
padding:5px 15px;
font-family:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<button>hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using [**Normalise CSS**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to ensure that your CSS rules are applied equally and uniformly across all major browsers.

This will solve your issue. If the issue remains please state clearly in your question (*edit*) that you have used normalise and any other CSS fixes you may have tried.

---

> i was searched and tried many of the same question answer.but its not working

Please outline *exactly* what you tried.

Comment: Thanks @martin .but the problem with `font-family` .i was changed now it working

Comment: @prasad pleased to see you found the problem. If you can answer your own question that would be grand.

Comment: Also, from the code you posted on your question; how would anyone ever know the problem was with `font-family`, as you don't mention it.

Comment: Yes i was not mentioned ..Now i was realised  the problem with `font-family`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this code, I hope it will work->

```
button {
  padding:5px 15px;
  -moz-padding:5px 15px;
}
```

Comment: I have checked your code it is working alright on my firefox  and chrome, however you can try above code maybe it helps on you pc;